# How do I select a value for a dropdownlist from a database in ASP.NET MVC and C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I have a `dropdownlist` which is stored within `TitleEditorTemplate`:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<string>" %>
<%=Html.DropDownList("", 
                      new SelectList(
                          new[] { "MR", "MRS", "MISS", "MS", "SIR", "REV", "DR"}
                      )
)%>
```

#### View

```
<%=Html.EditorFor(x => x.Title, "TitleEditorTemplate")%>
```

#### ViewModel

```
[UIHint("TitleEditorTemplate")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a title")]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

#### Controller

```
//Results of a query of textboxes
Title = data.Title,
```

#### Problem

My problem occurs when I'm trying to edit (pulling data from a database) the information and then write an `UPDATE` to the database, everything else is pulled back correctly and inserted into the correct textboxes.

However the `dropdownlist` automatically selects the first option 'MR' rather than 'MRS'.

I know it must have something to do with how it generates the `dropdownlist`but I don't know how to fix this.

#### DropDownList Code

```
<select id="Title_TitleDropDown" name="Title.TitleDropDown"><option>MR</option>
<option>MRS</option>
<option>MISS</option>
<option>MS</option>
<option>SIR</option>
<option>REV</option>
<option>DR</option>
</select>
```

What am I missing? How do I get it to choose the option selected from the database as the default selection?

For example:

Database columns

- Title: DR
- Forename: John
- Surname: Smith

When the user wants to update this information, they can do so. Within my aspx page it will popluate both the forename/surname textboxes however not the dropdownlist, this instead becomes the default value of "MR" so the name becomes Mr John Smith rather than Dr John Smith.

Comment: is it always "MR"? Nomather which option you select?

Comment: Yes, I think it must automatically select the first value. However if I pass this onto the next aspx page and then use my custom back button it remembers what has been selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SelectList takes a selected value as well as available options.

So this example should select MRS.

```
new SelectList(new[] { "MR", "MRS", "MISS", "MS", "SIR", "REV", "DR"}, "MRS")
```

**UPDATE**

Here is an example using RenderPartial...

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("ViewUserControl1", new DropDownModel {Name = "Title", SelectedValue = "MISS"});%>
```

You can use Model.Title instead of "MISS"...

Here is the DropDownModel

```
public class DropDownModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public object SelectedValue { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the partial view:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcApplication2.Models.DropDownModel>" %>
<%= Html.DropDownList("test", new SelectList(new[] { "MR", "MRS", "MISS", "MS", "SIR", "REV", "DR"}, Model.SelectedValue)) %>
```

This is just a quick mock-up that shows how you could do it - you might want to improve upon the concept!

Comment: Rather than , "MRS"). Do I have to pass through a Model?

Comment: That would be the ideal option - I'll be honest and say I've never done that using a template. I have used RenderPartial, with a partial view that has a real simple model that contains the "object SelectedValue"

Comment: It now selected the correct value using the 'SelectedValue', however the user hits the submit button the ViewModel has a blank value in both the Name/SelecteValue. How do I pull this information back out?

Comment: Ah, where I have put "test", you will need to use the appropriate name to match your model. For example "Customer.Title" or "Title" for example.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that the property name and the control name don't match. I suspect, though I haven't tested, that the select control is ultimately named Title.TitleDropDown. This prevents the default mapper from assigning the value.

Changing your drop down control to:

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("",new SelectList(new[] { "MR", "MRS", "MISS", "MS", "SIR", "REV", "DR"}))%>
```

should fix the problem.

Comment: I removed the "TitleDropDown" and still receive the same issue.